# Understanding XOR logical operator

Tags: ruby, language-agnostic

I don't understand this

```
2.0.0p247 :616 > 5 ^ 2
 => 7 
2.0.0p247 :617 > 5 ^ 1
 => 4
```

What 7 and 4 means in those scenarios?

I try reading here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_disjunction but cannot figure out by looking into the diagrams what is the subtract here. Sorry if this is simple math question.

Comment: Is this Ruby exclusive behavior? Why not tag it [tag:language-agnostic]?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has to do with the binary representation of the values.

```
5 = 0101
2 = 0010
1 = 0001
```

Now the XOR works like this:

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
```

so to compute 5 ^ 2, let's apply the `^` operation to *each column*:

```
0101   (this is 5)
0010   (this is 2)
----
0111   ==> which is the binary representation of 7
```

How did this work?  In the leftmost column, we computed `0^0=0`.  In the second column, `1^0=1`.  In the third column `0^1=1`, and so on.

and 5 ^ 1

```
0101   (this is 5)
0001   (this is 1)
----
0100   ==> which is the binary represenation of 4
```

Comment: Still don't get it. Why `5 ^ 2` seems to adds up and `5 ^ 1` subtracts in your samples?

Comment: Oh, sorry! Apply the `^` to each column.  It's neither addition or subtraction.  I will make the answer clearer.

Comment: Well thats my question. What it is instead? I'm having a hard time understanding the math here.

Comment: @Martin It XORs the *binary representation* of the numbers. XOR means only the bits which are not the same on both bit representations are set to 1.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Thanks!